# Evernote Windows SDK Csharp SampleAppAdvanced - can't authenticate

Tags: evernote

I am trying to run the Csharp sampleAppAdvanced from this code https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows

I substituted the consumer key and secret with those that I got in the email when I requested the API key.

```
ENSessionAdvanced.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("xyz","123","sandbox.evernote.com");

if (ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();
        }
```

But I always end up hitting an error at this point

```
ENNoteRef myRef = ENSession.SharedSession.UploadNote(myNoteAdv, null);
```

With exception reading "Exception of type 'EvernoteSDK.ENAuthExpiredException' was thrown."

On the console the error reads "EvernoteSDK: ENSession is unauthenticating."

Am I missing something? I know the Application is authorized for access.

The other sample code called  sampleApp, doesn't throw an error but doesn't display notes either.

Answer (score 0):

When you register the api, did you choose Basic Access or Full Access?

[image]